# Set values of a class based on XML strucutre

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I want to process certain elements of an `XML` string into an object based on the properties in the object matching up to the names of elements in the XML.

An example structure of the `XML` is as follows:

```
<Bar>
  <Body>
    <Header>
      <A>Value</A>
      <B>true</B>
    </Header> 
    <Data>
      <D>Value</D>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <D>Value2</D>
    <Data>  
  </Body>
</Bar>
```

There can be **MANY** `<Data>` elements in the XML, however `<Header>` only exists once. The class I have set up is as so:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string A { get; set; }
  public bool B { get; set; }
  public List<FooData> { get; set; }
  public void ProcessXml(string xml)
  {
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
    var propVals = (from ele in xDoc.Descendants()
                    join prop in this.GetType().GetProperties() on ele.Name.LocalName equals prop.Name
                    select new
                    {
                      prop = prop,
                      val = new Func<object>(() =>
                        {
                          object objValue = null;
                          prop.PropertyType.TryParse(ele.Value, ref objValue);
                          return objValue;
                        }).Invoke()
                    });
    propVals.ToList().ForEach(x => x.prop.SetValue(this, x.val, null));
  }
}
public class FooData
{
  public string D { get; set; }
}
```

I came up with the method `ProcessXml` which starts to set things up, however at the minute I am only ever setting `Header` values (A, B), any ideas on how I can add many `FooData` items into the `List` from within the same method easily?

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
  public static void TryParse(this Type t, object valIn, ref object valOut)
  {
    //Do some parsing logic
    try{
      out = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertFromInvariantString(valIn);
      return true;
    } catch(Exception) { return false; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the method `prop.PropertyType.TryParse` come from?

Comment: @mipe34 sorry it's an extension method, do you want me to include the code?

Comment: yes, it would help me to try your code ;-)

Comment: @mipe34 i've sussed this now so no need to worry and waste your time :)

Comment: Ok, but it would be nice if you could post the solution. It is an interesting question.

Comment: @mipe34 see my answer, and edit for the `TryParse` method.

Answer (score 1):

I went along a similar line as what I did with the header stuff as there isn't an easy way to combine this into one line.

```
var dataElements = (from dataDescendants in (from ele2 in xDoc.Descendants()
                                             Where ele2.Name.LocalName == "Data"
                                             select ele2.Descendants())
                    from dataDescendant in dataDescendants
                    join prop in typeof(FooItem).GetProperties() on prop.Name equals dataDescendant.Name.LocalName
                    select Element = dataDescendant, Property = prop, dataDescendants
                    group by dataDescendants into g = group
                    select g).ToList();
dataElements.ForEach(dataElement =>
                     {
                       FooItem fi = new FooItem();
                       dataElement.ToList.ForEach(x =>
                                                  {
                                                    object objVal = null;
                                                    x.Property.PropertyType.TryParse(x.Element.Value, objVal);
                                                    x.Property.SetValue(fi, objVal, null);
                                                  }
                       DataItems.Add(fi);
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your XML is really that simple, you can use Serialization to get this dynamic/self loading behavior, by decorating your model classes with the appropriate [XML Serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) though you will need at least 1 class for each level of indentation in the document:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<Bar>
  <Body>
    <Header>
      <A>Value</A>
      <B>true</B>
    </Header> 
    <Data>
      <D>Value</D>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <D>Value2</D>
    </Data>  
  </Body>
 </Bar>";

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Bar));
    serializer.Deserialize( new MemoryStream( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( xml ) ) ).Dump();
}

public class Bar
{
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Data[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

(**Edited**: I missed that there's only 1 Header element)